# MongoDB Atomicity Concerns -- Modifying a document in memory

Tags: python, mongodb, atomic

I'm working with MongoDB on my current project and a little confused about the proper way to build support for concurrent modifications.

I have an array of objects. When a request comes in, I want to inspect the last element in that array and make a conditional decision on how to respond. My code looks something like the following:

```
# Find the last object ID in the array.
last_element_id = str(document['objects'][-1])
if last_element_id != the_element_id_the_request_is_responding_to:
    db.documents.insert({
        ...
    })
else:
    # Append the response to the end of the array.
    document['objects'].append(new_element_id)
    db.documents.save(document)
```

I'm concerned about the situation in which:

1. In handling request A, I find the last_element_id is valid, and
   the response should be appended to the end of the list.
2. Before
   the append() and save() operations complete, another request, B, is
   handled.
3. B also sees the last_element_id is valid, appends() the
   response and saves().
4. Now, A's response is enqueued into the end
   of the array, but the response no longer follows the supposed
   'last_element_id' since B's response snuck in beforehand.

What is the proper way to handle this kind of logic in Mongo's atomicity model? I don't want to employ locks if I can avoid them, since the WSGI application may be run in multiple processes simultaneously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optimistic locking..,, one way is to add a field called version to the document and then increment it on every update, and when you update make sure that the version in the document is the same as the one you read in.

I could give more detail, but this is fairly well documented at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22

Let me know if this works for you,

Comment: It looks like this may work for what I'm doing! Thanks! Will report back.

Comment: @Shekar, you can simply achive this with findandmodify (this case). check my answer for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) to atomicallay handle the transaction (atleast this case).

This command accepts `upsert` flag, which you can use to update or insert the document based on its `existence`. Check the below example

```
> db.upsertTest.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ 1 ] }
```

and issuing this command with the query `_id:1` will push (append)  new item to arr

```
> db.upsertTest.findAndModify({query: {_id:1},update:{$push:{arr:2}},upsert:true,"new":true})
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```

and this will create a new one because the `_id:2` does not exist already

```
> db.upsertTest.findAndModify({query: {_id:2},update:{$push:{arr:2}},upsert:true,"new":true})
{ "_id" : 2, "arr" : [ 2 ] }

> db.upsertTest.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr" : [ 2 ] }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is the query support in findAndModify rich enough for what I'm trying to achieve? I only want to push the new item to the back of the array if the last item in the array is some known value. This known value is submitted as a parameter in the POST request.

Comment: Yeah you could do that with findAndModify. Its a perfect choice. In my above examples you can easily substitute your query and push to make it work..